# Enabling submit button after clicking textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code for enabling the submit button after clicking the checkbox.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="check"><a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="post" value="submit">
```

Script:

```
$('#check').click(function(){

if($(this).attr('checked') == false){
     $('#post').attr("disabled","disabled");   
}
else {
    $('#post').removeAttr('disabled');
}
});
```

But this is not working in my localhost. The button is enabled all the time even if the checkbox is not selected. Please help me to make it work.

Comment: The listener can be `this.form.submit.disabled = !this.checked` and you're done. But don't give form controls a name or ID of *submit* or any other standard form property name (like *post*).

Comment: The *checked* **attribute** sets the default checkedness of the checkbox. Adding and removing the attribute does not change the current value of the checked property (i.e. whether or not the input is checked), nor does checking for the presence of the attribute tell you whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#check').click(function() {
    $('#post').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
}
```

`.attr()` checks the attribute in the HTML, not the current state of the HTML; `.is(':checked')` tests the latter. Also, I believe it's preferable to use `.prop()` to change the disabled state of the element dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Does it disable it if you check, and then uncheck the checkbox? If so, then you just need to set disabled as the default state.

Comment: No the button is enabled all the time. If I set the default value to "disabled" then the button is disabled all the time even if the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Comment: Can you provide a live example?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.is(':checked')`

```
$('#check').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#post').attr("disabled","disabled");   
    } else {
        $('#post').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(this).attr('checked') will always true, it just read the "checked" attr value out,

use

```
this.checked
```

or

```
$(this).prop('checked')
```

See this:  http://jsfiddle.net/m6aBZ/

Comment: It is working fine in jsfiddle. But in my localhost it is not working. Button is enabled all the time.

Comment: That's werid, do you get any js errors, just alert(this.checked) to see its value

Comment: I tried giving alert. It displays true when the checkbox is checked and false if it is not checked. But the button is still enabled for both.

Comment: Then the problem is with $("#post").attr("disabled","disabled")?

Comment: I tried so many solutions. But still it is not working. The code which I posted in the question works in fiddle. I don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [filddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjs6c/)

Here is the javascript for working with it

```
$(function(){
$('#check').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')!="checked"){
        $("#post").attr("disabled","disabled");

    } else {
        $("#post").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: It is not working in my localhost. Is there something that need to be taken care while working on localhost?

Comment: @user2727874 Did you see any Console errors in developer tools of browsers

Comment: 1.ReferenceError: $ is not defined @ http://localhost/bt.html:4
2.The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ http://localhost/bt.html.. These are the errors which I get in console

Comment: Have you added `jquery.js` file to your html document ? If not add the reference to the jquery cdn -- > replace your jquery script tag with   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers.

Don't call any form control "submit" as it will shadow the form's submit method (i.e. `form.submit` will reference the control, not the method).

All you need is something like:

```
<form ...>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="this.form.submitButton.disabled = !this.checked" ...>
  <input type="submit" name="submitButton" disabled>
</form>
```